# Automapper initialize for T type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I want to have generic method to get data from database and pass model of how output data should look like.

I wrote simple method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetUsers<T>()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
         cfg.CreateMap<IQueryable<User>, IQueryable<T>>());

    return OnConnect<IEnumerable<T>>(db =>
    {
        return db.Users.ProjectTo<T>().ToList();
    });
}
```

Now I expected that I can do this:

```
var users = repo.GetUsers<UserViewModel>(); // it should be IEnumerable<UserViewModel>
var anotherUsers = repo.GetUsers<AnotherUserViewModel>(); // it should be IEnumerable<AnotherUserViewModel>
```

But I cant reinitialize `automapper` again. What should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize automapper only *once per application startup*.
2. You should know what types can be mapped from `User` already at the moment when you design a code in that case you can register all of them at a startup like this:

   ```
       Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
               cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto1>();
               cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto2>();
               ...
               cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDtoN>();
           });
   ```
3. Even if you will achieve it - it will not make a sense to try to map `User` to `Order`, but your architectural design will give that possibility
4. If you still want to do it(like I wrote in comments) - you can add somekind of marker attribute for Instance - MappableFrom(Type from), mark all DTO objects that can be used in scope of automapper. Then on initialization of your application - scan the assembly for all types that contains that attribute and register in Automapper.

Comment: If I have 100 viewModels I have to write 100 lines of initialization? Thats weird as hell.

Comment: @dafie In that case you can add somekind of marker attribute for Instance - `MappableFrom(Type from)`. Then on initialization scan the assembly for all types that contains that attribute and register in automapper.

Comment: If you have 100 view models representing the same content ... that's weird as hell

Comment: @Raphael No, 100 view models and each of which represent something different. On 1 page I need to have only user's `Id` and `Email`. On second I need to have `Id`, `Name`, and `LastName`. I have 1 model which represents data from database, and many viewModels which represents data which I want to send to `View` in `ASP.NET MVC 5` application.

Comment: @Raphael: I don't find that weir as hell. The problem with defining the mappings at startup is that at this point you need to know both, the presentation/business object and the DTO. It is valid to hide the DTO in the DAL and then map to a generic object  `T` that is unknown to the DAL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Profile to create all mappers follow this link http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Another approach you can initialize in a static constructor all the mapping you want by using some naming convention

In the below code, I'm mapping from same object type to same object type

```
// Data or View Models

public class AddressViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public AddressViewModel()
    {
        this.Address ="Address";
    }

}

public class UserViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        this.Name ="Name";
    }
}
public class BaseViewModel
{

}
```

Repository -- here I'm using same view model you should create Models here

```
public class CrudRepo
{
     public IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class, new ()
     {
        var data = new List<T> { new T() };
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<T>>(data);
     }
}
```

Then in of the static constructor initialize the mappers

```
    static HelperClass()
    {
        // In this case all classes are present in the current assembly
        var items = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                            .GetTypes().Where(x =>
                                              typeof(BaseViewModel)
                                              .IsAssignableFrom(x))
                            .ToList();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            items.ForEach(x =>
            {
                // Here use some naming convention or attribute to find out the Source and Destination Type
                //Or use a dictionary which gives you source and destination type
                cfg.CreateMap(x, x);
            });
        });
    }
```

Now you can create the instance of crud repository and get mapped items

```
    var userRepo = new CrudRepo();

    var users = userRepo.GetData<UserViewModel>();
    var address = addressRepo.GetData<AddressViewModel>();
```

`Note`: As long as property names and types are same the data will be mapped else you have to create ForMember